# How to dynamically nest directives in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

New to Angular and need some assistance.

I have a block of HTML content that will be coming from a database that will contain a group of widgets. These are simple widgets that will essentially render out various elements, but for the purposes of this question we'll assume they're all basic HTML inside.

Those widgets are included in an unpredictable way, so my first thought was to use directives to render the HTML. So, we'd have something like:

```
<div widget data="This is the content."></div>
```

So I've got a directive that will place the value of `data` into the `div`. Easy enough!

Now, how would I go about *nesting* those widgets? So, how would I get something like:

```
 <div widget data="Welcome! ">
    <div widget data="This is some inside content."></div>
 </div>
```

to render out:

`Welcome! This is some inside content.`

... because the issue I'm noticing is that if I place anything inside the directive HTML, it essentially gets ignored since it gets replaced with its own result (thus only echoing out `Welcome!`).

I realize I may be going the wrong direction on this in the first place, so any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: As long as the markup for the directives is not dynamic and your nesting is more of a partial view implementation, then you'll want to read up on **ng-transclude**: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you need to use the [`transclusion`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) feature of the directive combined with `ng-transclude` directive.

> Directive that marks the insertion point for the transcluded DOM of the nearest parent directive that uses transclusion.
>
> Any existing content of the element that this directive is placed on will be removed before the transcluded content is inserted.

A very basic version of transclusion of content based on your example might look something like this:

```
.directive('widget', function() {
  return {
    transclude: true,//Set transclusion
    template: '{{text}} <section ng-transclude></section>', <!-- set where you need to present the transcluded content -->
    scope: {
      text: "@"
    }
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('widget', function() {
  return {
    transclude: true,
    template: '{{text}} <section ng-transclude></section>',
    scope: {
      text: "@"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <span widget data-text="Welcome! ">
    <div widget data-text="This is some inside content.">
      <span widget data-text="This is some inside inside content."></span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me towards this. Definitely something to consider! One other possible angle to this, though... what if I wanted to nest a directive in this manner? Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tmcguire/q4h9x0tt/14/